# selenium 3.0 webdriver for safari 10 on windows

Tags: selenium-webdriver, safaridriver

I am using Selenium server 3.53 and using Safari browser version (5.1). When I try to open browser using Selenium on my Windows 10 machine, I got below error message.

> ("Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:
>   SafariDriver requires Safari 10 running on OSX El Capitan or
>   greater.")

Can some one help me how to install Safari 10 on my Windows 10 machine or is there any alternate way to tun Safari using Selenium?

Answer (score 0):

Vikrant , Apple's support for Safari on Windows stopped at 5.1 version, that means the latest safari you can install on Windows in Safari  5.1, why are you running your tests on safari which is very old and not supported by Apple?

Comment: thanks user8672807. Earlier i was not aware that apple stopped support after 5.1 version for windows. I think i need to use Mac machine to test safari browser.

Answer (score -1):

I think you will to use updated SafariDriver and browser

For your info

To use Apple's `SafariDriver`, you need to upgrade to El Capitan and Safari 10. To use the long deprecated Legacy SafariDriver, you need to downgrade to Selenium 2.x.

Read this link: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/3359

Comment: Can u help to install Safari 10 on my windows 10 machine

Comment: I will try, I try to give u some link which helps u